# How to create timetable based on time

Tags: php, mysqli, timetable

I am currently trying to do a monthly timetable.

[image: So here is my table named 'timetable']
and this is my coding **'table.php**'

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>8.00AM</th>
                                        <th>9.00AM</th>
                                        <th>10.00AM</th>
                                        <th>11.00AM</th>
                                        <th>12.00PM</th>
                                        <th>1.00PM</th>
                                        <th>2.00PM</th>
                                        <th>3.00PM</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <?php  
                                        $datequery="SELECT date  FROM day ";
                                        $resultdate = mysqli_query($con,$datequery);
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultdate)) {
                                    ?>
                                        <td><?php echo$row['date'] ;?></td>
                                        <?php  
                                        $query="SELECT c_name,l_name,time  FROM timetable
                                        ";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                        while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                        ?>
                                        <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==8]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                        <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==9]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                        <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==10]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                        <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==11]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                        <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==12]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                         <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==13]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                          <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==14]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                       <?php
                                            if($_GET['time'==15]){?>
                                                <td><?php echo $col["c_name"]; echo "<br>"; $col["l_name"];?></td>
                                        <?php }?>
                                        <?php }?>

                                    </tr>

                                    <?php }?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

The problem now is that I cannot display 'c_name' and 'l_name' based on 'time'.
So I need an idea on how can I arrange it according to time.

Answer (score 2):

Like already say Dan, you have an error with your condition with the time field

```
if($_GET['time' == 8])
```

this code will compare the string 'time' with the number 8 and return False. So your code will search the key False in your array. The good condition will be:

```
if($_GET['time'] == 8)
```

But you can avoid to check all value of the field time with a "where" clause in your SQL query. Instead make:

```
$query="SELECT c_name,l_name,time FROM timetable";
```

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT c_name,l_name FROM timetable WHERE time = ?;");
//Here you 'replace' the '?' caracter by the value of the variable $_GET['time']
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "d", $_GET['time']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $c_name, $l_name);
//here we fetch all returned rows by the sql query and display a line for each of them
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)){
    echo "<td> ".$c_name." <br> ".$l_name."</td>";
}
mysqli_stmt_close($query);
?>
```

Good practice would you sanitize your $_GET['time'] before binding it as a parameter for avoid SQL injection.

This will avoid to have many "if" for found the good entry. Your database will found more quickly the good entry than php.

For see more for prepare statement : http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php

And for sanatize your parameter:
http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Hope this will help you.

Comment: may I know "d" in this line means ? --> mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "d", $_GET['time']);

Comment: Sure, it's a parameter for define the type of the value, here is a 'double'. For example 's' will be for 'string'. More information
[here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't those if statements look more like

```
if($_GET['time'] == 8) { 
    // do something
}
```

?